# Counter for this, I still don't understand

Tags: python-3.5

I had previously asked about why my counter wasn't working. So, whilst working a different project, I realised I needed a counter but couldn't find or place one that fitted my needs. (I am also well aware that this could be shortened but ignore that). The counter needs to allow only 10 questions to be asked, but I just couldn't figure out how to adapt the others that I saw.

```
from random import randint
import random
import math


count = 0
print("This game is a quiz to see how good you are at maths. No paper allowed!")

def Start():
    print("No paper allowed nor a calculator!")

    ans1 = input("Do you wish to start? \n")
    if ans1 == "Yes" or ans1 == "yes" or ans1 == "Y" or ans1  == "y":
        Begin(count)
    if ans1 == "no" or ans1 == "No" or ans1 == "n" or ans1 == "N":
        exit()

def Begin(count):

    opers = ['+','-','*',"/"]
    operation = random.choice(opers)
    num1 = random.randint(2,21)
    num2 = random.randint(2,num1)
    num3 = int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))


    ans2 = int(input("What is "+str(num1) + operation + str(num2)+"? \n"))
    if ans2 == num3:
        print("Well done! You must be good at maths!")
        Begin(count)

    if ans2 != num3:
        print("You are terrible at maths. Go sit in that corner. (The answer was "+str(num3)+").")
        Begin(count)

def Replay():
    ans3 = input("Would you like to play again? \n")
    if ans3 == "Yes" or ans3 == "yes" or ans3 == "Y" or ans3  == "y":
             Start()
    if ans3 == "no" or ans3 == "No" or ans3 == "n" or ans3 == "N":
             exit()
Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

in Begin function add :

```
global counter
counter+=1
if counter == 10:
    print("something...")
```

**EDIT:**

this works!

```
from random import randint
import random
import math

count = 0
print("This game is a quiz to see how good you are at maths. No paper allowed!")


def Start():
    print("No paper allowed nor a calculator!")

    ans1 = input("Do you wish to start? \n")
    if ans1 == "Yes" or ans1 == "yes" or ans1 == "Y" or ans1 == "y":
        Begin()
    if ans1 == "no" or ans1 == "No" or ans1 == "n" or ans1 == "N":
        exit()


def Begin():
    global count
    count+=1
    if count==10:
        print("finished")
        exit()
    opers = ['+', '-', '*', "/"]
    operation = random.choice(opers)
    num1 = random.randint(2
                          , 21)
    num2 = random.randint(2, num1)
    num3 = int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))

    ans2 = int(input("What is " + str(num1) + operation + str(num2) + "? \n"))
    if ans2 == num3:
        print("Well done! You must be good at maths!")
        Begin()

    if ans2 != num3:
        print("You are terrible at maths. Go sit in that corner. (The answer was " + str(num3) + ").")
        Begin()


def Replay():
    ans3 = input("Would you like to play again? \n")
    if ans3 == "Yes" or ans3 == "yes" or ans3 == "Y" or ans3 == "y":
        Start()
    if ans3 == "no" or ans3 == "No" or ans3 == "n" or ans3 == "N":
        exit()


Start()
```

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, I put it in the wrong function. Thanks